# Consider the continuity of $g'(x)$

Tags: calculus

> $f(x)$ is continuous for $x\in (-\infty,+\infty) $. $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=A$.  $g(x)=\int_{0}^{1}f(xt) \text dt$. Find $g'(x)$ and discuss its continuity.

**My try:** $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=A$  hence $f(0)=0$. Then $g(0)=0$. For $x\ne0$, $$g(x)=\int_{0}^{1}f(xt) \text dt=\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}f(m) \text dm$$
Hence for $x\ne0$, $$g'(x)=\frac{f(x)x-\int_{0}^{x}f(m) \text dm}{x^2}$$
For $x=0$ $$g'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\int_{0}^{x}f(m) \text dm}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{2x}=\frac{A}{2}$$
Since $f(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, then $\int_{0}^{x}f(m) \text dm$ is continuous. So for $x\ne0$, $g'(x)$ is continuous. Also $$\lim_{x\to 0}g'(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}-\frac{\int_{0}^{x}f(m) \text dm}{x^2}=A-\frac{A}{2}=\frac{A}{2}=g'(0)$$ Therefore it is continuous at $x=0$.
Have I make a rigorous proof. Or is there more efficient way without discussing $x=0$.

Comment: It looks fine and I don't think there is a simpler argument.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Thanks. your comment means a lot.